# Is token replacement possible within a resx file?

Tags: visual-studio, resx

My resx file contains a chunk like this which specifies a *relative* path from the current (.\Properties) folder to the .\Assemblies folder:

```
   <data name="Axp_Calls" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
     <value>..\..\Assemblies\Axp.Calls.dll;System.Byte[], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, > PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
   </data>
```

What I'd like is to be able to put a token in the path, like this:

```
   <data name="Axp_Calls" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
     <value>$(SolutionDir)Assemblies\Axp.Calls.dll;System.Byte[], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, > PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
   </data>
```

But VS treats this as a *literal* string and doesn't replace `$(SolutionDir)` with the expected value.

My question is - what syntax would I used in my path for VS to expand the token correctly? Is it even possible?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying ultimately to do rather than how you decided to do it? Those macros ($(SolutionDir)) are designed to be consumed by the Build engine--unfortunately, there is no easy way to programmatically translate their values. It seems that what you're really trying to do is locate your compiled assemblies. If that's the case, there are better ways.

Comment: I'm trying to make the resx portable. Currently the .\Assemblies folder is two folder levels up from the .\Properties folder that contains the resx file.But I don't want to assume that hierarchy - which is why I wanted to refer to the .\Assemblies folder using a token rather than a hardcoded relative path.

Comment: If you did what you say you want to do, where would you define your token so that the resx remains portable?

Comment: Thanks for the interest - I'd expected to be able to use _SolutionDir_ or perhaps some other macro that VS makes available within Pre and Post build actions and within the project itself. When I tried this within the resx file it didn't work, which is why I posted the question.